# How to set the maxfun limit of the lbfgs solver on scikit-learn LogisticRegression model?

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, logistic-regression, solver

My scikit-learn LogisticRegression model, which uses the lbfgs solver,  is stopping early as shown in the logs bellow. The data is standardized.

```
(...)

At iterate13150    f=  4.05397D+03    |proj g|=  2.41194D+04

At iterate13200    f=  4.05213D+03    |proj g|=  1.36863D+04
.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py:444: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of f AND g EVALUATIONS EXCEEDS LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    5.5s finished

           * * *

Tit   = total number of iterations
Tnf   = total number of function evaluations
Tnint = total number of segments explored during Cauchy searches
Skip  = number of BFGS updates skipped
Nact  = number of active bounds at final generalized Cauchy point
Projg = norm of the final projected gradient
F     = final function value

           * * *

   N    Tit     Tnf  Tnint  Skip  Nact     Projg        F
   62  13240  15001      1     0     0   4.800D+04   4.051D+03
  F =   4051.0211050375365
```

sklearn uses the scipy implementation of the lbfgs solver. The function `scipy/optimize/_lbfgsb_py.py:_minimize_lbfgsb` has the following early stop conditions

```
            if n_iterations >= maxiter:
                task[:] = 'STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT'
            elif sf.nfev > maxfun:
                task[:] = ('STOP: TOTAL NO. of f AND g EVALUATIONS '
                           'EXCEEDS LIMIT')
```

I am indeed hitting the `sf.nfev > maxfun` limit. Unfortunatly, sklearn fixes the value of `maxfun` to 15_000 when it instanciates the scipy solver (`sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py:442).

When I hotfix the sklearn package to set maxfun to 100_000, the solver converges. But this is not a real solution (since I do not want to carry arround a custom sklearn dist with one different constant).

Any ideas on how to set the `maxfun` parameter in another way?

Comment: Would using `warm_start=True` and calling `.fit()` multiple times get you to convergence?

Comment: Created this issue to request control over this parameter: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/27484